# How to show last message when querying chat list in chat app using DynamodB

Tags: database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I wanted to build a chat app using DynamoDB, but having a hard time designing an architecture.
So, I do not need a complicated chat app like telegram, its rather simple. These are the queries that I need:

1. List chats for user (each chat also has lastMessageTimestamp, unreadCound and lastMessage)
2. List chat messages for chat
3. List users of chat (this is optional)

So far, I have come up with this [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT41J.png)

And [queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53m7U.png) to get data

The problem is that, to have data about lastMessage and unreadCount, I need to update 2 rows when creating the message. And transaction should be used for that, but I do not think that DynamoDB good for high transaction apps. Is there better way to do this (maybe using different technology)?

P.S. I know I should use RDB until I hit the bottleneck, but I have done this using RDB and now wanna try it using NoSql. I also had a look at MongoDB, but it does not support transaction if I have different schemas for chat and messages and want to update them in sync. I also may use streaming in DynamoDb to update values, but that's not going to be real time(

*Update*

I also could embed  messages in chat in mongodb, but is this scalable? I can push message as stack so would be easy to query latest messages, but what about pagination or infinite scroll, is there a way to make these queries fast? Also, what if embedded messages exceed the document size limit, how to scale then?

Comment: You say “I do not think that DynamoDB good for high transaction apps”. Where did you get this idea? Sure it is.

Comment: @hunterhacker, Documentation says that [it is not suitable for concurrent transactions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html#transaction-best-practices). _Multiple transactions updating the same items simultaneously can cause conflicts that cancel the transactions. We recommend following DynamoDB best practices for data modeling to minimize such conflicts._

Comment: I don't see where you'd have multiple transactions updating the same items simultaneously. Your design is minimizing such conflicts, right.

Comment: @hunterhacker let's assume two users insert message at the same time. I update chat row right after I insert message. So, if two users insert message and then they update the same chat row in transaction.

Comment: @hunterhacker, furthermore, if we have 100 members on chat, I would have to update 100 rows in transaction. I kind of feel like my db design is not the way to go. Do you know any other way to design db for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is definitely a suitable database for your needs here, but I think the design you've proposed isn't the right approach.

Your requirements are (I've split some up from your original post):

1. List chats for user
2. List chat messages for chat
3. List users of chat (this is optional)
4. Get last message for a chat
5. Get unread count for a chat+user

If you have a DDB table with:

- PK: chat_id
- SK: timestamp:message_id

And a GSI with:

- PK: user_id
- SK: timestamp:message_id

You can do a query for chat_id to complete requirement #2, getting all messages in a chat, sorted by time posted.

You can have a second table that handles permissions like:

- PK: user_id
- SK: chat_id

With a GSI:

- PK: chat_id
- SK: user_id

You can do a query on the permissions table to get all chat_ids for a user_id, and a query on the permissions gsi table to get all user_ids in a chat, satisfying requirements 2 & 3.

For requirement 4, this is pretty easy as you can just do a query on the chats table, with a max count of 1, which will get you the last message and the time it was last posted.

Requirement 5 is a little more tricky, but if you can keep track of the last time a specific user has viewed a chat, you can do a query with a range expression on the sort key such as timePosted >= timeLastSeen, and the number of messages you get is the unread count. It makes sense to me to store the time last viewed on client side, but if you want this to be stored server side you could make a third table.

All the operations above are highly scalable and you won't run into any concurrency issues, even with 100 users in the same chat.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your time! But with this schema I would have to query unread count and last message for chat with separate queries. So to get list of chats (with unread count and last message ) for user I am going to have 1 query to get a list, another 2 batch read queries to get unread and last message. Do you think there is a way to build a schema so that we can query chat list with unread count and last message?

Comment: Batch query is not a DDB operation. You would have to do multiple queries, yes, but this is highly optimized for writing data, and each read operation is cheap and scalable so it's still a decent approach